# Proof of an approximation in a research paper

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

The paper can be found at this link: [http://www.columbia.edu/~sk75/sinica.pdf](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Esk75/sinica.pdf). The proof is not given but there is a reference to the paper: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00531747 which has a proof but the conclusions do not match and I cannot figure out a connection. So I need either to make such a connection. Or prove the following theorem myself.

In the first paper, the most important theorem is proved solely based on the theorem 3.1 (on which I need help proving) which states

> **Theorem:**
> For any constants $b\geq y$ and $b>0$, as $m\rightarrow\infty$,
> $$\mathbb{P}\Big(\ U_{m}<y\sqrt{m}\ ,\ \tau'(b,U)\leq m\ \Big)\\
> =\mathbb{P}\Big(\ U(1)\leq y\ ,\ \tau(b+\beta/\sqrt{m},U)\leq1\ \Big)+o(m^{-1/2})$$
> where the constant $\beta=-(\zeta(\frac{1}{2})/\sqrt{2\pi})$. Where $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function.
>
> Here:
>
> - $\tau'(b,U):=\inf\{n\geq1:U_{n}\geq b\sqrt{m}\}$,
> - $\tau(b,U):=\inf\{t\geq0:U(t)\geq b\}$ and
> - $U_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(Z_{i}+\frac{v}{\sqrt{m}}\right)$ where $Z_i$ is a standard random variable and $U(t):=vt+B(t)$ where $B(t)$ is the standard Brownian motion.

I really don't know how to prove this and my supervisor is really busy. So I would really appreciate some guidance or just a complete proof.

Thank you so much!

Comment: It seems like the first equation featured in page $242$ of the Siegmund-Yuh paper you linked might be the connection, with your $b$ being their $\zeta$, your $y$ being their $\zeta - x$, your $U_m$ being their $s_m$, and then I assume (emphasis on assume) that you can translate or adapt things between your $\tau$ and $\tau'$ and their $\tau$, their $m_1$, and their $R_m$.

Comment: @BrunoB thank you for the answer! I indeed can connect the LHS as in the first paper there is a "drift" but in the second paper $s_m$ is just a sum of iid random variables. I have a problem with the RHS. In the second paper the approximation is given by Petrov's paper (1965) and it doesn't create a connection between the discrete case and the Brownian motion case. So I cannot show the RHS's are equal.